# Can Vim/GVim Show Other Files within the Same Project while Editing a File?

Tags: vim, ide

While I am editing a file in Vim, I need to see other available files to edit within the same project. Are there any project management features for Vim (GVim actually, if it makes any difference), either natively or in plugin form?

I'm not looking for anything extravagant, just something which will keep my files under one project name, and some sort of buffer which will display what files go under what project. You know what I mean, you see it in every IDE.

Comment: When I read "project management" I thought of something like MS Project.  May consider rewording the subject.

Comment: @Steve Rowe - You've got rep. Feel free to change, if you've got a better idea. I won't mind.

Comment: @Thomas Geritzma Which one did you use?? I see you have selected an answer but that answer has many options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have used the [Project](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) plugin for quite sometime.  I've been fairly happy with it.  I did make one modification to mine, so that I can generate tags over a whole project.  It's fairly easy to add a new project to the Project window with the "\C" command inside the window.  It will prompt you for certain parameters such as path, target directory, project name, and file types to include, then it will recurse the path to find all your files and then display them in the window.  Be sure to save it!

The downside of Project plugin is that it only keeps track of files and does not track certain environment variables related per project.  Not a big deal if you only have one project.  The Project plugin can keep track of multiple projects in it's window by adding more, but you can't really "switch" between project environments seamlessly.

That is why I find [SessionMan](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010) indispensable for project session management.  Comes in handy when jumping back and forth between different code projects. I basically give each session a name similar to my project name.  With each session, I map the project plugin command (:Project YourProject)) to a key where I can retrieve the project in each session. Also, it helps to keep your paths saved on a per session basis. This facilitates tag lookup for omnicomplete and tag navigation as well as the "gf" key combo for opening header files.

Those two plugins work great together.

There is a newer plugin called [MyProjects](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2556), but the last I tried it had some window and buffer issues that I'm not used to. It also didn't work well with my session management plugin.  It's still in early development.

EDIT:  I also just found [exVIM](https://github.com/exdev/exvim) online.  It looks interesting and might be up your alley.  I may have to try it out myself. Note that there are multiple install options.

Answer (score 25):

[NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) with bookmarks does the job for me. It's popular and has been updated recently, whereas Project hasn't been updated in a few years.

Commands

```
:Bookmark proj1 " to bookmark a directory
:NERDTree proj1 " opens NERDTree with bookmarked directory set as tree root
```

Even has handy filesystem commands for creating/deleting files/directories etc

Comment: Although it isn't actually a "project" plugin, I think I like this one the most. At least, it gives you a "tree".

Comment: How do you differentiate between files belonging to a project and just files in the directory in question, in NERDTree?

Answer (score 2):

The exVim may fulfill your demand. It have a project window can browse a specific directory, also some useful plugin to ease the develop.

Here is the link:
http://code.google.com/p/exvim/

Answer (score 0):

Found an interesting link [here](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/). It's primarily Python-focused, but I think it'll get you started.